# How does .NET implement a mutex?

Tags: c#, .net, mutex

I understand the concept of a mutex. It was very well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524/what-is-a-mutex).

But now I want to know what a mutex really is. My guess is that .NET is taking some primitive system resource (maybe even just a memory address?) and wrapping it in an object that it calls a mutex.

Anyone know exactly how a mutex is achieved in .NET?

Comment: May also be related: [How are Mutexes Implemented, Language Agnostic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485924/how-are-mutexes-implemented)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it just wraps a Win32 Mutex object.  Are you looking for details on how the Win32 mutex is implemented?

Comment: @Michael: If that's true, can we drill that down then. How is a Win32 mutex implemented?

Comment: CLR source code is available, Windows' isn't.

Comment: For native mutex implementations, folks have had a go answering over here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414106/native-mutex-implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How a mutex gets implemented is quite likely hardware-dependent. Most CPUs have some sort of atomic compare-and-swap instruction that provides the guts of the thing.

But yes, under the hood, it's just a semaphore — a thing (word, probably) whose value indicates whether its signaled or not. The OS provides a means for a thread or process to do an idle wait, waiting for the semaphore to enter the desired state. Most implementation, I believe don't guarantee the order in which a thread might gain ownership of a mutex — just because you were first in line, doesn't mean that you'll be the first to get it.

Comment: "it's just a semaphore" - That's what I thought! It seems like it would just be a simple semaphore that's just ratcheted down to one thread getting access to the resource. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164040.aspx will give you the details. .NET Mutexes are based at the end of the day, on Win32 thread primitives, though some things are a bit different (remember that the 'lock' statement works on any object, so there are some things in the CLR called SyncBlocks that deal with that).